# ¿Cuál es la validez de la palabra "ocupar" en vez de "usar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

En ocasiones escucho y veo que se usa la palabra "ocupar" para dar a entender que se está haciendo uso de algo.

Si bien en ocasiones cuando se dice que se usa algo claramente se ocupa también.

> Voy a **ocupar** esta silla, está vacía.

o

> Seguramente yo puedo **ocupar** ese cargo.
>
> Esa tarea es fácil, puedo **ocuparme** de ella.

Sin embargo en las siguientes oraciones no puedo evitar sentir un uso indebido de la palabra basado en las definiciones de la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qu5i3z8)

> El software que yo **ocupo** es muy bueno para la edición de imágenes.
>
> He escuchado a mucha gente **ocupar** la forma con subjuntivo en ambas cláusulas.

Quisiera saber si es correcto darle dicho significado a la palabra.

Comment: No se si sea correcto pero esta manera de expresar la palabra  "Ocupar" la escucho mayormente en países como Chile.

Comment: En España suena incorrecto.

Comment: Soy chileno y no se me habría pasado por la cabeza suponer que los ejemplos de abajo estén incorrectos. Gracias por la información, voy a poner más cuidado.

Comment: @Rodrigo me parece muy curiosa la manera que tenéis de _ocupar_ la lengua ;-)

Comment: En México también es muy frecuente, pero en Colombia nos suena incorrecto.

Comment: @fedorqui - I don't know, maybe you're just trying to be funny -- but I don't think that way of using "ocupar" works.

Comment: @aparente001 I am not very sure about what you are referring to. I was making a joke with Rodrigo about the usage of _ocupar_ as a synonym of _usar_, as the question was mentioning. So I was saying _me parece muy curiosa la manera que tenéis de *utilizar* la lengua_ making use of _ocupar_ in the sense they use in Chile (and we do not in Spain). Not sure if this clarifies my comment :)

Comment: @fedorqui - I'm okay with *ocupar un software* or *ocupar un modismo* but *ocupar la lengua* sounds far-fetched to me.

Comment: @aparente001 & fedorqui En Chile no hay problema con _ocupar la lengua_. En este diálogo yo entiendo el chiste, pero en cualquier otra circunstancia un chileno lo pasaría por alto porque, de hecho, usar y ocupar son sinónimos para nosotros.

Answer (score 9):

Viene recogido en el [Diccionario de americanismos 2010 de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=ocupar).

> ocupar. I. 1. tr. Mx, Ho, ES, Ni; Ec, Bo:NE,O, Ch, Ur, pop + cult →
>   espon. Usar algo.

Comment: ¿Esto quiere decir que por ejemplo la frase: "El software que yo ocupo es muy bueno para la edición de imágenes." es correcta?

Comment: Al parecer en ciertos usos del español, si. En mi entorno sonaría muy rara.

Comment: Creo que en el ejemplo del software, la palabra "ocupar" toma el lugar de la palabra "necesitar" y el decir que ocupo el software indica que lo necesito para trabajar (Monterrey, México).

Answer (score 0):

Hay países como Chile donde OCUPAR reemplaza el verbo USAR y en otros, como México, en los cuales reemplaza a NECESITAR. A los argentinos esto nos suena raro y confuso si no estamos acostumbrados a hablar con personas de esos países.